# Lookup in Dataweave Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb

I am doing a lookup in dataweave

`lookup("myflow",$)`

> I am passing entire xml to the flow called. The data received in the flow is of type 
>    'java.util.LinkedHashMap'. I am trying to put a ForEach processor and specify the xpath3 in collection. This get's errored out with message:
>
> Root Exception stack trace:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Could not transform input of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to a
>   supported one. Supported types are
>   'SimpleDataType{type=org.w3c.dom.Document, mimeType='*/*',
>   encoding='null'},SimpleDataType{type=org.w3c.dom.Node, mimeType='*/*',
>   encoding='null'}`

How should i do this as i need to iterate over the xml received and produce string output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above scnario is not possible. In this case if we pass the entire xml then its type will be changed. A better approach while using lookup in dataweave is to pass simple values such as string, integer etc..